# Python threads: synchronize shared data

Tags: python, multithreading, synchronization, deadlock

Im new in python, I'm trying to develop an application with simple menu:

1. Create new thread which starts a counter
2. Kill the thread
3. Check the counter value
4. Exit from application ensuring the thread go finish

The thing is, AFAIK there is always a main thread and I should synchronize main thread and the new thread created in the "option 1" to access (read/write) the shared data.

The following code actually works, but if I uncomment the lines `#with my_mutex:` to set synchronization then the application waits forever.

Is there a deadlock that I don't see?
Any of my reasoning is wrong?

```
import time;
import threading;

#shared data
go_on = True;
count = 0;
my_mutex = threading.Lock();

def  count_thread():
    global go_on;
    global count;
    global my_mutex;
    c = True;
    while c:
        with my_mutex:
            count += 1;
            time.sleep(1);
            if go_on == False:
                c = False;



def create_new_thread():
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=count_thread, args=());
    t1.start();


while True:
    print("Select an option");
    print("1. Create a new thread");
    print("2. Kill the current thread");
    print("3. Check counter");
    print("4. Exit");

    user_input = int(input());

    if user_input==1:
        create_new_thread();

    elif user_input==2:
        #with my_mutex:
            go_on = False;

    elif user_input==3:
        #with my_mutex:
            print("Current value: "+str(count));

    elif user_input==4:
        #with my_mutex:
            go_on = False;
            break;

    else:
        print("Invalid option");
```

Answer (score 3):

The `while` loop in `count_thread` almost never releases the mutex.

You should probably change it so the lock is only held when changing `count`.

```
def  count_thread():
    global go_on;
    global count;
    global my_mutex;
    c = True;
    while c:
        with my_mutex:
            count += 1;
        time.sleep(1);
        if go_on == False:
            c = False;
```

Comment: +1 Correct. I tried to post the same code. you are faster than me :).

Comment: Actually in the OP's code the lock does have a chance to be released and acquired by the main thread at some point, it depends on thread scheduling and it may take some iterations of the loop - so it's not a complete deadlock... Nevertheless, your solution should fix the OP's problem. +1 (edit: maybe the code accessing `go_on` _should_ remain in the protected section. Shouldn't be critical for this example, but generally that's what one would want)

Comment: Thanks @mskimm, as mata point there is a chance to the lock get realease, so i don't understand why deadlock happens. Nevertheless your solution works and I included if condition inside of synchronized block :). Finally i think the problem is in sleep method.